# Excel sumifs entries in current week

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

I have the following table that calculates the total hours worked each day

`Total (real)` = `End (real)` - `LUNCH` - `START`

I need to calculate the number of hours worked so far only in the current week.  I have tried `SUMIFS()` to compare the weeknum and year of the data to only sum data from the current week.  I am saving this to a cell off the screenshot.

This is the jist of what I would like to achieve.  I recognize the syntax is off:
`=SUMIFS(G:G,A:A,WEEKNUM(A:A)==WEEKNUM(TODAY()),year(A:A)==year(today()))`

Where is my syntax heading off track?

Note - Not using a pivot table for this application.  So I need this to be formula-based.

[image: Excel hours table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this that finds the date of Sunday before and Saturday after and uses them as brackets:

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,A:A,">=" & INT((TODAY()-1)/7)*7+1,A:A,"<" & INT((TODAY()-1)/7)*7+8)
```